# JToolBar prevent minimize

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

JToolBar can be attached and detached from the frame or panel into a separate window. 
So I want to use it as set of emergency commands and indicators. The problem is when detached if you minimize the frame to which it belongs , the toolbar also minimizes , I want for it to stay on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
 the toolbar also minimizes , I want for it to stay on the screen
```

Set the toolbar not float-able. As a sample code

```
JToolBar toolbar=new JToolBar();
toolbar.setFloatable(false);

...
toolbar.add(YourCompoenthere);

...
```

It will restrict the toolbar to detach from frame or panel. see [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html#setFloatable%28boolean%29) and an [Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)